# Is KEDA support statefulset scaling?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, keda

I'm trying to scale my Statefulset object horizontally using KEDA with K8S.

I put in the 'deploymentName' key the value of my Statfulset name but the scaling is not taking into action.

Is KEDA suuport it?

```
apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    deploymentName: test-statefulset
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    deploymentName: test-statefulset #my statefulset name
  pollingInterval: 30
  cooldownPeriod:  300
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 6
  triggers:
    - type: rabbitmq
      metadata:
        host: rabbitmq_host
        queueName: "test.queue"
        queueLength: "5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not supported yet. Check the discussion [here](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/497).

Comment: No longer true - see https://keda.sh/docs/2.6/concepts/scaling-deployments/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it support Statefulset
you have to mention it explicitly under .spec.scaleTargetRef
go through [scaledObject](https://keda.sh/docs/2.3/concepts/scaling-deployments/)

Comment: Yes. This is a new feature Keda supplied in the latest version. Thanks for adding this answer despite it was not true the date it been asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported now: https://github.com/kedacore/keda/pull/731
Look at the Docs: https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/concepts/scaling-deployments/#scaling-of-deployments-and-statefulsets